# animate the current_page_item highlight in wordpress using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints, magicline

I am creating a website for portfolio and learning purpose and I am new to web programming so sorry if i made some stupid mistake in code :)

I want to single page scrolling website with a simple fixed position menu at the top, with little animation during the page scroll for that i took a reference from http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/. Here is what i achieved so far http://www.pk-pixels.com

Beside on hover event i want the line to animate to next/prev item when user scroll the page upwards or downwards. So i used jquery waypoints plugin to generate an event

I am successfully able to move the highlight to current item when user scrolls the page but only problem is that it does not animate(some time it does strangely....), here i need your help just make that line animate when page scrolls :), here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var $menuline = $("#menuline");
linePosition($menuline);
$('#page1').waypoint(function() {
        $("#main-menu ul li").removeClass("current_page_item");
        $("#main-menu ul #link1").addClass("current_page_item");
        linePosition($menuline);
}, { offset: -10 });

$('#page2').waypoint(function() {   
   $("#main-menu ul li").removeClass("current_page_item");
   $("#main-menu ul #link2").addClass("current_page_item");
  linePosition($menuline); 
});
});
function linePosition($menuline)
{
$menuline
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left);
var $linewidth = $menuline.width();
    var $lineposition = $menuline.position().left;

 $menuline.animate({
        width: $linewidth,
            left: $lineposition
       });
}
```

here is html code for the menu

```
   <nav id="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item" id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li id="link4"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li id="link5"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <div id="menuline-container">
            <div id="menuline"></div>
        </div>
     </ul>          
     <!-- <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?> --> 
   </nav>
```

Please help me on this one :)

Thanks

Comment: Please i am stuck on this problem someone help ...

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas that may help

Firstly create real page links for each menu item not just # as the below code depends on what page link is the current page to work

Secondly you have getton rid of the "$("#example-one").append("");" line of the magicline script and hardcoded the magic line and I am not sure that the animation will work this way

Answer (score 0):

here is some code that relates to the current_page_item class - the animation won't work without something like this

```
<nav id="main-menu">

    <li id="link1" role="navigation" class="page_item <?php if(is_page('home')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="home">Home</a></li>

    <li id="link2" role="navigation" class="page_item <?php if(is_page('about-us')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="about-us" >About Us</a></li>

    <li id="link3" role="navigation" class="page_item <?php if(is_page('Services')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="Services" >Services</a></li>


    /*this link has multiple pages still highlighting Projects as the current_page_item in the case that you have subpages under one menu link*/
    <li id="link4" role="navigation" class="page_item <?php if(is_page('projects')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?><?php if(is_page('project_1')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?><?php if(is_page('project-2')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?><?php if(is_page('project-3')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="videos" title="link to videos">Projects</a></li>

    <li id="link5" role="navigation" class="page_item <?php if(is_page('contact-us')) echo ' current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="contact-us" >Contact Us</a></li>

     </ul>

    </nav>
```

Comment: hi jen, thanks for your response. As i already told i am able to move highlighter to current_page_item, all i need is to animate the line during the page change. That also happens but some time like if i double scroll using the mouse wheel. I am not sure what is stopping it to animate when scroll values change slowly.

Comment: I think you keep the magic line code as true as possible. I think you not javascript the current_page_item and hard code the magicline. I think you should copy the structure of the original demo more closely and javascript the magicline animation and hard code the current_page_item with page anchor links??